# pandas groupby head() & tail() not fetching correct values

Tags: pandas, group-by

I have a dataframe as below

```
     id     s   e   sa  ea
0   AAA     2015-04-22  2015-11-11  2015-05-07  2018-09-28
1   AAA     2015-05-07  2018-09-28  2015-05-07  2018-09-28
2   BBB     1972-11-04  2019-08-01  2019-06-15  2019-12-31
3   BBB     2019-06-15  2019-12-31  2019-06-15  2019-12-31
4   CCC     2000-11-04  2005-11-04  2000-11-04  2019-01-01
5   CCC     2006-11-04  2019-01-01  2000-11-04  2019-01-01
```

When I do `groupby` & select `head(1)` & `tail(1)`, i get wrong values

```
df1.groupby('id').head(1)
```

gives me

```
    id  s   e   sa  ea
0   AAA     2015-05-07  2015-11-11  2015-05-07  2018-09-28
2   BBB     2019-06-15  2019-08-01  2019-06-15  2019-12-31
4   CCC     2000-11-04  2005-11-04  2000-11-04  2019-01-01
```

and `df1.groupby('id').tail(1)` gives me

```
     id     s   e   sa  ea
1   AAA     2015-05-07  2018-09-28  2015-05-07  2018-09-28
3   BBB     2019-06-15  2019-12-31  2019-06-15  2019-12-31
5   CCC     2000-11-04  2019-01-01  2000-11-04  2019-01-01
```

Any idea why this is happening? 
even the index numbers are correct. values of only one column seem to be wrong!!!

Put a pic to show the errors as well
[image]

Comment: I'm using `pandas` v 0.25.  When I use `.head(1)` and `.tail(1)`, your desired output is produced.  Perhaps you need to `conda update conda` & `conda update --all` at the `anaconda` prompt or just `conda update pandas`.  An additional FYI, `df1 = df` does not produce a copy of the `df`, this just `df1` just points to `df`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you should use `first()` and `last()` instead of `head()` and `tail()`.

```py
>>> df1.groupby('id').first()
              s           e          sa          ea
id
AAA  2015-04-22  2015-11-11  2015-05-07  2018-09-28
BBB  1972-11-04  2019-08-01  2019-06-15  2019-12-31
CCC  2000-11-04  2005-11-04  2000-11-04  2019-01-01


>>> df1.groupby('id').last()
              s           e          sa          ea
id
AAA  2015-05-07  2018-09-28  2015-05-07  2018-09-28
BBB  2019-06-15  2019-12-31  2019-06-15  2019-12-31
CCC  2006-11-04  2019-01-01  2000-11-04  2019-01-01
```

Comment: I had tried `first()` and `last()` as well & there also i was getting the same result. I restarted my machine & i am getting the proper results with `head(1)` and `tail(1)` itself !!! Very strange.